# Ruby-like squish in Haskell

Tags: beginner, strings, haskell

`squish` is an onomatopoeic string function provided by Ruby on Rails that works on strings.

Given a string, `squish` condenses all the consecutive spaces into one.<sup>1</sup> (Imagine that you take a string at both ends and compress it with both hands, spaces will be merged and you will hear the typical `squish` sound).

I went I little overboard and wrote three variations of this function:

- `squishAll` that will squish together all repeated chars:
  `squishAll "aaabbbccc" -> "abc"`
- `squishOn` that will squish together any specified char:
  `squishOn 'a' "aaabbbccc" -> "abbbccc"`
- `squish` for spaces only: `squish "foo   bar   baz" -> "foo bar baz"`

```
import Data.List
import Data.Foldable

squishAll :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
squishAll = (map head) . group

squishOn :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
squishOn item = Data.List.concat . (map firstIfEqualElseAll) . group 
  where firstIfEqualElseAll (x:xs) = if x == item then [x] else (x:xs)

squish = squishOn ' '

main = print $ [squishAll "aaabbbccc", squishOn 'a' "aaabbbccc", squish "foo   bar   baz"]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The Ruby function that this is modelled on would also remove any spaces at the start and at the end.  I've chosen not to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

I have no complaints about this.

Esthetically it seems that `squishOn 'a' "aaabcbcbc"` should create the groups:

```
[ "aaa", "bcbcbc" ]
```

instead of:

```
[ "aaa", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "c" ]
```

Due to laziness it may not make any difference. This is something that perhaps should be benchmarked. To form the groups the first way use the `groupBy` function from `Data.List` like this:

```
groupBy (\x y -> x == y || (x /= 'a' && y /= 'a')) input
```

So, two characters are in the same group if they are equal or if they are not both the character to be squished. Of course, if you do this you'll have to switch the groups back together differently with something like:

```
concatMap f (groupBy (\x y -> ...) ...)
  where f ('a':xs) = "a"
        f xs       = xs
```

(Substitute the literal `'a'` with the squishing character.)

This alternate approach probably makes more sense if you were to define squishing on ByteString or Text.